# php How to access array inside array

Tags: php

I have an array which is of the following form in PHP-

```
Array(
 0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'var1=\'some var1\'',
    1 => 'var2=\'some_var2\'',
    2 => 'var3=\'some_var3\'',
  ))
```

and I want it to appear as-

```
array (
    0 => 'var1=\'some var1\'',
    1 => 'var2=\'some_var2\'',
    2 => 'var3=\'some_var3\'',
  )
```

So how to do it?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: $array = $other_array[0];

Comment: Got what I was wrong at. Just outputting some other variable and expecting it to output some other variable. Sorry for such stupidity

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried...

```
$inner_array = $outer_array[0];

var_dump($inner_array);
```

...?

Read [here in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) about more details to arrays in php.

Answer (score 0):

Multidimensional arrays generally work as shown below

```
$shop = array( array("rose", 1.25 , 15),
           array("daisy", 0.75 , 25),
           array("orchid", 1.15 , 7) 
         ); 


echo $shop[0][0]." costs ".$shop[0][1]." and you get ".$shop[0][2];
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of foreach construct is as follow:

```
foreach ($array_expression as $value) {
   statement
}

foreach ($array_expression as $key => $value) {
   statement
}
```

The first form loops over the array given by $array_expression. On each loop, the value of the current element is assigned to $value and the internal array pointer is advanced by one so that on the next loop, the next element is accessed.

The second form does the same thing, except that the current element’s key will be assigned to the variable $key on each loop.

The foreach syntax above is also similar to the following while construct:

```
while (list(, $value) = each($array_expression)) {
   statement
}

while (list($key, $value) = each($array_expression)) {
   statement
}
```

Even for loop can be used to process and loop through all elements of arrays with the following syntax:

```
$count = sizeof($arr_expression);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
   $value = $arr_express[$i];
   statement
}

for ($i = 0, $item = ''; false != ($value = $arr_expression[$i]); $i++) {
   statement
}
```

Nested loop of “foreach” can also be used to access multidimensional arrays. Here’s an example array and the way to access its value data. For example:

```
foreach ($array_expression as $arr_value) {
   foreach ($array_value as $value) {
      statement
   }
}
```

Here’s an example code to access an array:

```
$contents = array(
   "website_1" => array("name" => "StackOverFlow",
                        "url" => "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
                        "favorite" => "yes"),
   "website_2" => array("name" => "Tip and Trick",
                        "url" => "http://www.tipandtrick.net",
                        "favorite" => "yes")
);
```

To retrieve the data, programmers can specify the keys that lead to the value directly with the following syntax, which will print the “My Digital Life”.

```
echo $contents['website_1']['name'];
```

However, the syntax above becomes unpractical when dealing with large arrays, or when the name of the keys and values changed dynamically. In this case, the “foreach” function can be used to access an array recursively.

```
foreach ($contests as $key => $list) {
   echo "Website No.: " . $key . "\n";
   echo "Name: " . $list['name'] . "\n";
   echo "URL: " . $list['url'] . "\n";
}
```

The output will be:

```
Website No.: website_1
Name: StackOverFlow
URL: http://www.stackoverflow.com/
Website No.: website_2
Name: Tip and Trick
URL: http://www.tipandtrick.net/
```